# Looking for a specific function for speed/curvature relationship

Tags: functions

I have the following problem:

Given $x \in [0,1]$, the speed of my car in percentage, and $y \in [0,1]$, the curvature of the road ahead of me (e.g. $y==0$ straight line, $y==1$ some maximum curvature, suppose $90°$).

I want a function $f(x,y) \in [0,1]$ that:

1. Penalizes (i.e. $f(x,y) \rightarrow 0$)  when the speed is low and the road is straight, or when the speed is high and there is a sudden curve.
2. Rewards (i.e. $f(x,y)\rightarrow 1$) when the speed is high and the road is straight, or when the speed is slow and there is a curve.

In a formal way I want:
$\begin{cases} 
f(x,y)\rightarrow 1, & \mbox{if } x>>y\\
f(x,y)\rightarrow 1, & \mbox{if } y>>x\\
f(x,y)\rightarrow 0, & \mbox{if } y\rightarrow 0 \mbox{ and }x\rightarrow 0\\
f(x,y)\rightarrow 0, & \mbox{if } y\rightarrow 1 \mbox{ and }x\rightarrow 1\\
\end{cases}$

Can someone help please?

Edit:
More over it has to approach $1$ when the two variables approach $0.5$, that is:

$f(x,y) \rightarrow 1 \mbox{, if } x \simeq 0.5 \mbox{ and } y \simeq 0.5$

Comment: What is it that you’re trying to model with this? Your “curvature” seems to reflect the overall change in direction required when navigating a turn, but in real life whether you’re entering a turn too fast or too slowly instead depends largely on the _radius_ of the curve, which is closely related to the mathematical meaning of curvature. You have to go much slower to make a right-hand turn on the street than to negotiate a gentle turn on the highway that changes your direction of travel from north to east.

Comment: My curvature is a measure of how rough is the curve. It is based on a maximum curvature register on my track of about 90°, so it is normalized in the range $[0,1]$.
For the radius part you mentioned, is there any formula to estimate the radius of a curve given a set of $n$ points?